# Grails - Select box tied to object ID and remote field

Tags: ajax, grails

Run into a bit of an odd problem that is increasingly frustrating

Scenario: I have a list of domain objects, each has a g:select attached to it that is rendered by a remote field.

How do I tie the status variable OR the personInstance ID to the selection box, so that when I use the renderField, I update testDiv_(number)

View:

```
<g:each in="${listOfPeople}" status="i" var="personInstance">
<td>
    Text: <g:remoteField action="getResults" controller="person" id="" update="testDiv_${personInstance.id}" paramName="search" name="getResults" value="" />
    <g:each in ="${personInstance?.choices}" var="choice" status="x">
        <li>${choice}</li>
    </g:each>
</td>
<td>
    <g:render template="renderThisTemplate"></g:render>
</td>
</g:each>
```

Template:

```
<div id="testDiv_${personInstance.id}" class="testDiv_${personInstance.id}">
    <g:select id="aChoice" name="aChoice.id" from="${allChoices}" optionKey="id" value="" />
    <g:actionSubmit action="addChoice" value="Add"/>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I know that the remote call (ajax) is passing the update for testDiv_(number). The problem is with the template ID and assigning that value to the template div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone needs this answer in the future. Apparently you cannot reference the instance variable (personInstance) in the g:each from the template.

So I replaced the g:render with its code and it worked:

```
<g:each in="${listOfPeople}" status="i" var="personInstance">
<td>
    Text: <g:remoteField action="getResults" controller="person" id="" update="testDiv_${personInstance.id}" paramName="search" name="getResults" value="" />
    <g:each in ="${personInstance?.choices}" var="choice" status="x">
        <li>${choice}</li>
    </g:each>
</td>
<td>
<div id="testDiv_${personInstance.id}" class="testDiv_${personInstance.id}">
    <g:select id="aChoice" name="aChoice.id" from="${allChoices}" optionKey="id" value="" />
    <g:actionSubmit action="addChoice" value="Add"/>
</div>
</td>
</g:each>
```

Comment: You can if you pass the instance to the template - <g:render template="renderThisTemplate" model="[personInstance: personInstance]" />  Also, render is an "empty" tag so you don't need to have an ending  </g:render> - just use "/>"